# How do you ask the host of a party if all of the invitees arrived colloquially?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Image I am at a party and I go up to the host to ask if all of the people he/she invited are here/ have arrived.

I am trying to think of a way to ask this colloquially. Can you guys give me some suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

> Is everyone here yet?

is colloquial in that it is idiomatic, but it could certainly be used formally as well. It would be understood as meaning

> Is everyone invited here yet?

This is an example of ellipsis.

Answer (score 0):

> Has everyone arrived [yet]?
>
> Has everyone turned up [yet]?
>
> Are all the guests here [yet]?

The possibilities are huge.